# ADFS integration with Hybris

Tags: integration, adfs, sap-commerce-cloud

Have Recently started going through the documents about active directory for the authentication and would like to understand more about. Am working as Hybris developer. How to use ADFS as Authenticator in hybris project? Please guide me if there are any examples for such case or any documentation available. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Hybris uses SAML.

Basically add Hybris as an ADFS SP.

e.g. [this](https://auth0.com/docs/protocols/saml/adfs).